# How to refer to images stored in SHA1 hash form in django template downloaded by scrapy

Tags: python, django, django-templates, scrapy, sha1

i used dynamic django scraper to scrape items from some site. I downloaded image and are saved in desired location but i cannot access them from django template. The images are saved in SHA1 hash. 
Is there a way to access them from django template?

In my models the images are saved as,

```
Image: u'http://www.market1/ScaledImages/180x180x2/Global-BlaBand_Bistro_kastikkeet.jpg'
```

but when i see the folder where i have saved them , the filename is in the form of SHA1 Hash.

In my django template i did

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}Image/{{item.image}}">
```

But still , I can't access the image . 
However if i do

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}Image/38ce4c28e9969cdcf02bf74293d512faf1dc37da.jpg">
```

i.e refer to SHA1 hash i can access them.

Is there a way to access images  without using hard-coded code? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is a simple cryptographic hash function,

why don't you just convert bellow url

Image: u'http://www.market1/ScaledImages/180x180x2/Global-BlaBand_Bistro_kastikkeet.jpg'

in sha-1 and then fine the image in directory with that SHA-1 ?

other then that you can simply override the image storage mechanism , and can store images with their url rather then SHA-1